# How to map an Option case class

Tags: scala

Say, there is a case class

```
case class MyCaseClass(a: Int, b: String)
```

and an `Option[MyCaseClass]` variable

```
val myOption: Option[MyCaseClass] = someFunctionReturnOption()
```

Now, I want to map this Option variable like this:

```
myOption map {
  case MyCaseClass(a, b) => do some thing
}
```

It seems the compiler reports error like `It needs Option[MyCaseClass], BUT I gave her MyCaseClass, bla bla..`. How to use pattern match in Optional case class ?

Comment: Your code is correct. There should be no compilation errors.

Comment: Do you mean `match`?  As @orionll said, with `map` your code is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider extracting the `Option` value like this,

```
myOption map {
  case Some(MyCaseClass(a, b)) => do some thing
  case None => do something else
}
```

or else use `collect` for a partial function, like this

```
myOption collect {
  case Some(MyCaseClass(a, b)) => do some thing
}
```

**Update**

Please note that as commented, the OP code is correct, this answer addresses strictly the *last* question *How to use pattern match in Optional case class ?*

Answer (score 0):

```
MyOption match {

   Some(class) => // do something
   None => // do something. 

 }
```

Or

```
MyOption map (class =>//do something)
```